# How do I make method that creates generic class object?

Tags: java, class, generics

I'm new at java programming and from couple of days I struggle with writting a method that would take parameter of type T and create new object of generic class.
Here is what I've got so far:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private BST gc;

    public <T> void MakeGenericClass(T type)
    {
        gc = new BST<type>();
    }
}
```

Eclipse editor says that: type cannot be resolved to a type.
I would appreciate any ideas.
J.K.

Comment: `type` is the variable, not the type. Use `new BST<T>()`.

Comment: Please change your question with relevant details from your real scenario. What you're doing here is nonsensical. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Also, the member variable is declared with a raw type: it should either be `private BST<?> gc`, or you need to move the type variable from the method to the class.

Comment: Thanks for advice ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally need to pass a `Class<T>` object to use to make the object.

```
<T> T makeOne(Class<T> itsClass) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return itsClass.newInstance();
}

public void test() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Test aTest = makeOne(this.getClass());
}
```

Unfortunately `Object.getClass()` returns a `Class<?>` which doesn't help much with the next step. We need to use a cast to get around that.

```
<T> T makeOne(T template) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return makeOne((Class<T>) template.getClass());
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like what they are trying to do. From their example, they are trying to instantiate `BST`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Perhaps the second example is closer to what you think the question is asking.

Comment: I'm confused now, which of you methods represents their `MakeGenericClass`? What is `this` in your example? Is it their `BST`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - As the example is syntactically wrong with `type` (`T type` as parameter and `new BST<type>()` as a `class`). I am relying mostly on the title of the question.